# VHDL delayed monostable initialisation

Tags: vhdl

Idea is to generate a delayed pulse when Trig input is activated, both delay and pulse width are adjustable respectively with 'delay' and 'ton'. I use an integer counter to compare delay then delay+ton to toggle the Pulse output.

The issue is that timing sequence starts just after board programming: sigPulseCounter is incremented ... even if signals are initialized. Any tips ?

Reset works well and Trig also but there is an unwanted pulse on startup.

Thanks for your feedback.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DelayedMonostable is
    generic(
            delay :integer:= 2*40000000;
            ton :integer:= 2*40000000);
    port (
            Clk: in std_logic;
            Reset: in std_logic;
            Trig: in  std_logic;
            Pulse: out std_logic;
            Debug: out std_logic);
end DelayedMonostable;

architecture Behavioral of DelayedMonostable is
-- Signal declaration
signal sigPulseCounterEnable: std_logic := '0';
signal sigPulseCounter : integer := 0;      
signal sigPulse : std_logic :='0';          
signal sigDebug: std_logic := '0';

begin

    Debug <= not sigPulseCounterEnable;
    Pulse <= not sigPulse;

    Counter : process(Clk, Reset)
    begin
        if Reset='0' then
            sigPulseCounter <= 0;
                sigPulseCounterEnable <= '0';
            sigPulse <= '0';

          elsif Trig='0' then
            sigPulseCounter <= 0;
                sigPulseCounterEnable <= '1';
            sigPulse <= '0';

          elsif rising_edge(Clk) then

                if(sigPulseCounterEnable='1') then

                    if(sigPulseCounter = delay) then
                        sigPulse <= '1';
                    end if;

                    if(sigPulseCounter = delay+ton) then
                        sigPulse <= '0';
                        sigPulseCounterEnable <= '0';
                        sigPulseCounter <= 0;
                    end if;

                    sigPulseCounter <= sigPulseCounter + 1;

                end if;

        end if;
    end process Counter;

end Behavioral;
```

I have tried to invert the Trig logic in the process without success:

```
elsif Trig='0'
```

with

```
elsif Trig='1'
```

**EDIT:**

I have split in 3 parts the architecture, each assign value to a signal or port - Works good now.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DelayedMonostable is
    generic(    
          delay : integer := 40000000/2;
          ton : integer := 2*40000000);

    port(   
        Clk: in std_logic;
        Reset: in std_logic;
          Trig: in  std_logic;
        Pulse: out std_logic;
        Debug: out std_logic);
end DelayedMonostable;

---------------------------------------

architecture Behavioral of DelayedMonostable is
-- Signal declaration 
signal PWMCounter : integer;
signal sigTrig: std_logic;

begin

    Debug <= not sigTrig;

    Counter : process(Clk, Reset)
    begin
        if (Reset='0') then
            PWMCounter <= 0;

        elsif(rising_edge(Clk) and sigTrig='1') then

            if(PWMCounter = ton+delay) then
                PWMCounter <= 0;
            else
                PWMCounter <= PWMCounter + 1;
            end if;

      end if;
    end process Counter;


    Trigger: process(Reset, Trig)
    begin
        if (Reset='0') then
            sigTrig <= '0';

        elsif (Trig='0') then
            sigTrig <= '1';

        elsif (PwmCounter = ton+delay) then
            sigTrig <= '0';

        end if;
    end process Trigger;


    Generator : process(Clk, Reset)
    begin
        if (Reset='0') then
            Pulse <= not '0';

        elsif(rising_edge(Clk)) then

            if(PwmCounter=delay) then
                Pulse <= not '1';
            end if;

            if(PwmCounter=delay+ton) then
                Pulse <= not '0';
            end if;

        end if;

    end process Generator;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Does it work as you expect in simulation?

Comment: As soon as the simulation environment is ready I will. I have tried directly on a dev board with Cyclone IV. Did you find something incoherent ? Regards.

Comment: `Trig` is not in the process sensitivity list. But why is the signal used asynchronously at all? Is everything clock synchronous? Are you using proper input timing constraints? Else you're asking for metastability issues...

Comment: also: if `signal sigPulse : std_logic :='0';` and `Pulse <= not sigPulse;`, then of course `Pulse` will be `'1'` at start-up. And about `Trig`: is it by any chance `'0'` when you start-up?

Comment: @JHBonarius: I previously tried to add `Trig` in the sensivity list and to detect a change with `falling_edge(Trig)` but I got an "Error (10820): its behavior depends on the edges of multiple distinct clocks". Sorry, I forgot to mention that I/O are complemented on the board, when outputs are 1, leds are off.

Comment: That's because you shoudn't add `falling_edge(Trig)`... In your code, `Trig` works as a second asynchronous 'reset' input for two signals, and as an asynchronous 'set' signal for a third. But your earlier attempt does seem to indicate that we're helping you with an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. Maybe you should rephrase your question to explain your initial intention.

Comment: My initial intention is to generate a delayed `Pulse` when there is an edge on `Trig` with the capability to `Reset` the `Pulse` at any time. Thanks for XY !